# Configure SAML 2.0 With SP

Tags: php, xml, saml-2.0, onelogin

We have made a Web-based application in PHP. and now client want to configure SAML - one login to the system.

I have created an IDP and app to one login. Login/logout is working fine.

Now the client has given us one XML(to use in IDP) so what will be the use of that XML to configure with our service provider. please help me out.

I have attached a screen shot of that XML.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is metadata and is normally used for configuration without having to do it manually.

What IDP are you using?

Is this metadata for the client (SP) or the IDP?

Normally an IDP / SP has the ability to import metadata which is where you would use this file.

Comment: we use **onelogin** as IDP.  and this metadata is for IDP. an you know how we can use this metadata to authenticte to our SP (application) ? using onelogin.com

Comment: This provides the IDP endpoints to use in your SP. You need to import into your SP. However, since you say it already works, just ignore it.